# MVC: where to place permission check logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a kind of blog. There are users, communities, posts, comments.
When user is about to reads his friend's posts, the system must check "READ" permission for this user to every that post. The logic for evaluating that permission can be heavy (depending on communities and friends blogs setting, on frendship status etc), and the better way to check it would be an database stored procedure while fetching that list of posts :))
But i use classic repository/service pattern and put my business logic into service layer. I store my "CanRead", "CanUpdate" etc checks there as well.
I'm afraid that filtering posts in the service layer will be an expensive thing...
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never put these granular task based checks like this in the `[Authorize]` attribute like @smartcaveman says.

Eventually granular role based permissions need some kind of link pruning, ie *don't show a link unless the user has permissions*.  By putting the tons of granular permission checks into the authorize attribute the MVC internals grind away faking up requests to check those authorize attributes.

So what happens is 10 attributes = 10 checks, 100 = 100 checks, 1000 = 1000 checks PER page.  This is really really bad.

It sounds like what you really have is user based multi-tenancy.  In this case then putting these type of queries directly in your database layer is the right thing to do.  Nothing says you can't use a stored procedure with the Repository pattern.

Comment: So, i need to build my-friends-posts-list in the stored procedure? Sounds like i'm doubling some checking logic...

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET MVC, the most appropriate point for evaluating user permissions is with a custom `AuthorizationFilter` attribute on the Controller action.

Here is an article on [Implementing a Custom ASP.NET MVC Authorization Filter](http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/07/08/implementing-a-custom-asp.net-mvc-authorization-filter.aspx).  This example uses role-based security, but there is nothing to stop you from using any other system of authorization logic.

Comment: You will also want to consider caching security credentials/token/whatever you come up with.

Comment: how to handle the user permissions has been changed in database.

Answer (score 0):

Jim, first thing to point out is try to keep the business logic as much inside of your application as possible. That means to treat your database purely as a store for data. Therefor your domain logic should remain in your asp.net code.

In regards to your problem, I suggest to design your system such that at the time of "reading" there is no need to filter and therefore slowing down delivery. This means having an index of what can be seen by who which you is automatically maintained as data get's added, updated and deleted.

You may find this solution time consuming to implement. However if filtering data while viewing is an expensive operation, then this work is well worth your time.